# A tournament graph where all the in-degrees and out-degrees are different.

Tags: graph-theory

I want to show that for every integer $n$ there exists a tournament graph with $n$ vertices where all the in-degrees are different, and all the out-degrees are different.
My first thought was induction but I have been trying to form a result with no effect. Any suggestions?

Comment: Won't a "transitive" graph (i.e., A beats B and B beats C implies A beats C) do the trick?

Answer (score 2):

Why doesn't induction work? By assumption we have such graph on $n$ vertices. Now add another vertex which is source (it has outdegree = $n$) in new graph and we are done.

Comment: In fact, you don't even need induction: just construct the graph directly by placing the vertices in a row and drawing the edge $uv$ if $u$ is to the left of $v$.

Comment: @ChristianF well, can't there be any other vertex already existing that is a source? This way not all the in-degrees are different.

Comment: @Théophile can you explain your answer a bit more please? Cause from what i understand this way every node will have the same in and out degree.

Comment: Of course there is in $n-$ graph. But adding new vertex it indegree became 1

Comment: @ChristianF Oh yes I feel dumb. Thanks again!!

Comment: @TheDeC My construction creates the same graph as ChristianF's: when doing the induction step, add the new vertex to the left of all the others.

Comment: @Théophile ah that's what you meant. Thank you both for the input.